# Sync Exchange Calendar with iCloud Calendar on iPhone

Tags: macos, ios, calendar

I have an Exchange account at work that contains my calendar. I'd like to sync that Exchange calendar with my iCloud Calendar on my iPhone so that I can see and create appointments on my home computer (that cannot see the Exchange server because it's behind the work firewall.)

Does anyone know of an app or technique that will sync two calendars within an iPhone?

(There are many answers about syncing between iPhones, but that is not the question here.)

(There are also answers from seven years ago, but those really aren't duplicates of this question because they've aged out.)

Comment: Then how are you getting to the Exchange server on your phone? VPN? If not, you should be able to add an Exchange account from System preferences > Internet Accounts and click on the Exchange Account creation tool.

Comment: No. Exchange works on the phone without VPN but not on the desktop. 

You'd think it would!

Comment: Try Microsoft Outlook, it's free in the App Store. If that works then your problem is likely mail.app or one of its preferences.

Comment: But that doesn't solve my problem of getting the dates into the iCloud world.

Comment: That shows you where the problem is.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that there is no conduit from my work exchange account and my iCloud account.  I was hoping that someone had created a tool that would sync calendars from different sources within the iPhone.

Comment: Correct, except that you can have both your iCloud and Exchange calendars visible combined at the same time in your calendar view. Giving you a **view** that approximates what you want. I am aware of no utilities that will sync one with another.

Comment: That's what I feared. I want to be able to see my exchange dates on my Mac without my Mac having to VPN into work (which it can't do.)